# jQuery selector for each first element on every parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="iconset"></span> <!-- want to select -->
    <span class="iconset"></span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span class="iconset"></span> <!-- want to select -->
    <span class="iconset"></span>
</div>
```

I need to select the first element of every `.container`, using:

```
$(".container .iconset:first");
```

I get only one element, the first found. And using

```
$(".container .iconset");
```

I get all 4 elements. I don't want to check the index for even or odd because more elements could be added later.

How can I build a selector to return all first elements on every container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This uses [the first child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), which will only select the `.iconset` if it is the first child of its parent.

It also uses the `>` children selector, since `.iconset` is a direct child of `.container`.

```
$(".container > .iconset:first-child");
```

You were using [the first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), which narrows the entire matched set down to the first one.

Comment: I remember seeing this, but I never dropped by to see what it does. Thanks! Also adding nth-child: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: @Bruno - You're welcome. And yes, nth-child could be used as well. :o)