# jQuery select first accordion in each tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, tabs, jquery-tabs

I have a page that uses jQuery tabs. Each tab contains one or more jQuery accordions, which are generated dynamically, in addition to other stuff. Example:

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab">
    <div>
        Some stuff
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        I am an accordion
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <div class="accordion">
        I am also an accordion
    </div>
    More stuff
    <div class="accordion">
        I am also an accordion
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the first accordion in each tab to remain open, while the others (if there are any) are collapsed. I have tried:

```
$('.tab .accordion:first')
```

which only selects the first accordion on the page (obviously). I also tried:

```
$('.tab .accordion:first-child')
```

This selects the first accordion in tab2 but it doesn't select the one in tab1 because there's some stuff above it. I've also tried:

```
$('.tab > .accordion').filter(':first-child')
$('.tab').children('.accordion:first-child')
```

Along with about every combination of selectors I can think of. At this point my brain is fried. Before you point me to a duplicate question, none of these are asking the same question exactly:

[JQuery Tab each Selected tab first text box focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178898/jquery-tab-each-selected-tab-first-text-box-focus)

[jquery select first child with class of a parent with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406332/jquery-select-first-child-with-class-of-a-parent-with-class)

[jQuery selector for each first element on every parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968853/jquery-selector-for-each-first-element-on-every-parent)

[jQuery Selecting the first child with a specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766652/jquery-selecting-the-first-child-with-a-specific-attribute)

The difference in my case is I have very little control over what content shows up in these tabs.

Comment: How about $('.tab').each(function(){var firstAcc = $(this).find('.accordion').eq(0);})?

Comment: Crap... found the answer as soon as I asked. `$('.accordion:first-of-type')` That's a freebie.

Comment: Actually, `:first-of-type` _doesn't_ work in the example I provided above because it matches the first div element, not the first element with the accordion class. See David Thomas's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.tab').find('.accordion:first');
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KZnwa/).

Comment: Works great. I would use this but I like the elegance of `:first-of-type` a little more :)

Comment: You know you can answer your own question, right? If you want to use a different answer, or find a different answer better suits your needs, you don't have to accept an answer posted by someone else, just answer your own question and accept that answer! (Though, admittedly, you have to wait two days to accept, but even so...)

Comment: Yeah but that would be a waste. Someone might as well get the rep for it. Not that you need it necessarily ;)

Comment: Actually, `:first-of-type` _doesn't_ work in the example I provided above because it matches the first div element, not the first element with the accordion class. I could change the first div to a p tag or something, but the solution you gave is less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.accordion:first', '.tab')
```

Comment: This selects the first accordion as well as each tab.

Comment: It shouldn't, the way it's written it should look within the `.tab` (the context) for the `.accordion:first` element. This approach is valid but, internally, switches it around to use the syntax from my own answer.